# How can invoke WebService with SOA on C#?

Tags: web-services, soa

İ have webservice!i calling webservice then i take result!
Then i wanna call webservice with Soa!
   Soa is as an architecture!

So can you help me?

Comment: Take your SOA and bend it around the webservices tooter! Then tug gently on the soa!

Answer (score 0):

As you say SOA is an architecture.

You call a web service using a technology.

But you use SOA principles to design the signature of your web service.